# Does delete [] run in O(N) time?

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer

When you deallocate an array using `delete [] name`, does this take O(N) time by looping through the array and deleting everything inside, or does this just delete the array itself?

Comment: Is there a requirement in the Standard for `delete[]` to be O(n)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends.

If there is a destructor for the type stored in `name`, then yes, [each of those destructors are run, then the memory is deallocated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete). Assuming that destructor runs in O(1) time, this would be an O(N) process.

If it's a type that doesn't have a destructor (primitive types, for example) the memory will just be deallocated (presumably in O(1) time, though I don't see any standard guarantees relating to this).

Comment: Note that this O(N) complexity is for the number of destructor calls. If the destructors themselves have worse than constant complexity, then that complexity is compounded for each call.

Comment: @eerorika a destructor whose runtime depends on how many other instances you destroy? unlikely, no? (but not impossible)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 There can be other inputs to consider. Consider for example the destructor of `std::vector<std::string>`. Deleting an array of those would have complexity of O(N*M) where N is number of vectors and M is the number of  strings.

Comment: The compiler only has to produce the same result as if they were each run. It can certainly optimize this to be faster than O(n) if it can figure out some way to do so. The destructors, for example, might optimize to nothing at all. Or they might to optimize to decrementing a variable and then the compiler might consolidate those decrements.

Comment: @eerorika it would still scale linearly with number of element in the array that is destructed

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes. But having linear complexity in relation to one input doesn't mean that the complexity is linear in general. Consider for example multiplying all elements of a matrix. It's true that the complexity is linear in number of rows, but that can be misleading since the complexity is quadratic in number of elements.

Comment: Definitions of computational complexity depend on a definition, sometimes implicit, of what counts as a single "operation". This is why the Standard has https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/container.requirements.general#2